# How to make webkit free canvas context memory when canvas is destroyed

Tags: javascript, iphone, memory-leaks, canvas, webkit

The code below seems to leak memory at a rather alarming rate on webkit (mobile safari & konqueror). I realize the test case could be rewritten to reuse the canvas instead of creating a new one, but I'm wondering why the below doesn't also work. Any insight would be appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function draw() { 
    var holder = document.getElementById("holder");
    holder.innerHTML = "<canvas id=cnv height=250 width=250>"; 
    var ctx = document.getElementById("cnv").getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(50,50);
    ctx.lineTo(Math.random()*100,Math.random()*100);
    ctx.stroke();
}

function start() {
    setInterval(draw, 100);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="start()">
<div id="holder"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue happens on Webkit even when an image SRC is modified, so I don't get surprised if this happens when handling canvas too.

There is a bug filled on Chrome (that made them filling a bug to Webkit) and we hope this will be fixed soon, as it is making many Chrome extension unusable.

references
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=36142
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23372

Anyway, the suggestions above should mitigate this.

Comment: Thanks for the links - I'd actually run into memory leaks with images in the past too, so it's interesting to know where the trouble lies.

Comment: That underlying webkit bug was first reported Jan '09. Ouch. Sure is frustrating when your product fails because of a browser bug that may never get fixed.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't:**

- Create the `<canvas>` element with `.innerHTML`
- Create the `<canvas>` in each Interval

**Do:**

- use `var cv = document.createElement('canvas'); cv.setAttribute('height', '250'); // ...`
- cache the reference of `cv` at some init point and re-use that!!

---

```
    <script>
            var holder = document.getElementById("holder"),
            var cv = document.createElement('canvas');
                cv.setAttribute('id', 'cnv');
                cv.setAttribute('height', '250');
                cv.setAttribute('width', '250');
                holder.appendChild(cv);

            function draw() {                     
                var ctx = cv.getContext("2d");
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(50,50);
                ctx.lineTo(Math.random()*100,Math.random()*100);
                ctx.stroke();
            }

            function start() {
                setInterval(draw, 100);
            }
    </script>
```

Comment: I realize creating a new element 10 times a second is inefficient - this was test code to track down a memory leak, not production code. That said, I have control over the content but not the app which is loading it, which makes reusing an existing canvas a little inconvenient. Even with lazy code, WebKit shouldn't leak memory like that.